# CRM - 2015 - CheckBoxes

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

IS this possible to have check boxes in crm 2015 page (not through web resource) , I tried to implement couples of solution with js but did not work out. Any comments would be useful.

Comment: Questions on SO need to be more focused. With respect, this is too broad...

Comment: I think it's a fine question - especially considering the fact that it received a specific answer, and that answer was voted as helpful by the community

Answer (score 13):

You can add checkboxes by creating fields of type two options. Then, add them to an entity form and in the field properties window, change the format to "checkbox".

Check this out: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/dynamics/crm-customer-center/create-or-edit-entity-fields.aspx

**Possible data types for a field**

> Two options
>
> After creating this field, configure it in the form to which it was added. In the form, select whether the field is displayed as option buttons (also known as radio buttons), a check box, or a list.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In the Dynamics CRM entity form editor:

- Click <kbd>New Field</kbd> button on the extreme down-right corner
- Provide **Name** to the field
- Set data type as **Two options**
- Save the record
- Drag this newly added field into the form from the right side field list
- Click **Change Properties** in the menu bar
- In the pop-up click the **Formatting** tab
- Select `Two radio buttons / Check box / List` in the **Control formatting section**
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>